# Camel property placeholder boolean

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have a property in my property file:

```
glob.dev_environment=true
```

or

```
glob.dev_environment=false
```

Now I've tried the following:

```
<route id="emailMonitor" autoStartup="${!glob.dev_environment}">
    <from uri="{{imapURL}}" />
    <bean ref="attachmentProcessor"/>
</route>  

<route id="emailMonitor" autoStartup="${not glob.dev_environment}">
    <from uri="{{imapURL}}" />
    <bean ref="attachmentProcessor"/>
</route>  

<route id="emailMonitor" autoStartup="{{!glob.dev_environment}}">
    <from uri="{{imapURL}}" />
    <bean ref="attachmentProcessor"/>
</route>  

<route id="emailMonitor" autoStartup="{{not glob.dev_environment}}">
    <from uri="{{imapURL}}" />
    <bean ref="attachmentProcessor"/>
</route>  

<route id="emailMonitor" autoStartup="{{glob.dev_environment == 'false'}}">
    <from uri="{{imapURL}}" />
    <bean ref="attachmentProcessor"/>
</route>  

<route id="emailMonitor" prop:autoStartup="!glob.dev_environment">
    <from uri="{{imapURL}}" />
    <bean ref="attachmentProcessor"/>
</route>
```

I'm going a bit crazy here.  How do I get it to evaluate a boolean in XML DSL?
Yes, I've read [this section](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/using-propertyplaceholder.html#_using_property_placeholders_for_any_kind_of_attribute_in_spring_xml_files), and [this section](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/using-propertyplaceholder.html#_reverse_a_boolean_value).
I bet changing to `glob.prod_environment` would make this easier, because the XML DSL probably can't handle boolean operations.  Am I right?  Is that what's going on?

Comment: You can test if `{{!glob.dev_environment}}` works on a camel route and if it does then it would suggest that the syntax simply isn't supported by route autostartup field. I would however advice against configurations like `dev_environment` and instead advice to use individual configurations like `email.monitor.autostartup` then either set the default values so that they match dev environment or have separate config file development, testing and production.

Comment: What Camel version do you use, as the ! negate is added in a release of Camel 3.x

Comment: Claus, I'm using Camel 2.21.0.  Any solutions for evaluating a negated boolean property value, for 2.21.0? Is {{glob.prod_environment}} the solution, because negation isn't available?  We're unlikely to upgrade to v3.  Pasi - thanks, there's a different config file per environment.  For me, configuring 1 property is better than configuring 10.

Comment: Ok, it's working without the negation.  eg. autoStartup="{{email.monitor.autostartup}}" .  For future readers, prop:autoStartup (first link in question) isn't working, at least for Camel 2.21.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments above...

Camel property value negation only works in v3.x.
The [prop: prefix](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/using-propertyplaceholder.html#_using_property_placeholders_for_any_kind_of_attribute_in_spring_xml_files) doesn't seem to work in v2.x either.

Workaround solution was to use a property that didn't require negation.